# MacBook main volume can't be mounted during boot

Tags: hard-drive, partition, startup, mount, efi

MacBook 7.1 (white unibody) from 2010, I have upgraded to a new SSD some years ago. During startup the MacBook turns off when the loading bar is at about 80%. Booting in verbose mode I can see the error message for about 3sec before the computer switches off (haven't found out how to stop it from shutting down to have a more detailed look at the output). I took a picture of the error:
[image: Boot Error Message]

This is a transcript of the image (some more details appear during shutdown for split of a second, but I haven't been able to capture it.

```
...
disk0s2: I/O error
jnl: disk0s2: update_fs_block: failed to update block 2 (ret 5)
jnl: disk0s2: journal_open: Error replaying the journal!
hfs_mount: journal_open == NULL; couldn't be opened on MacBookSSD
mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
mount_hfs: Invalid argument
Tue Dec ... localhost com.apple.xpc.lauch[1] <Emergency>: Boot task failed: mount
Tue Dec ... localhost com.apple.xpc.lauch[1] <Emergency>: Shutting down in 3 seconds.
```

I have booted in recovery mode (cmd + r) and tried to do the "First Aid" and it appeared to be successful: Volume MacBookSSD appears to be ok, Exit-Code 0. However the error remained.

I have further tried the following:

- Safe start (boot holding SHIFT). Same error appeared during startup.
- FSCK in recovery mode using terminal:

  ```
  fsck_hfs -fy /dev/rdisk0s2
  ...
  ** The volume MacBookSSD appears to be OK.
  ```
- Tried to mount the device manually (same error as above):

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/3
  /sbin/mount_hfs /dev/disk0s2  /tmp/3
  mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
  mount_hfs: Invalid argument
  ```
- Reset NVRAM (cmd + Alt + p + r during startup)
- Reset SMC (Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Power)

Edit: I have tried booting in single user mode (cmd + s during boot) and ran

```
fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk0s2
```

again. Output is:

```
** /dev/rdisk0s2
** Root file system
Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
The volume name is MacBookSSD
** Checking extents overflow file. 
** Checking catalog file. 
** Checking multi-linked files. 
** Checking catalog hierarchy. 
** Checking extended attributes file. 
** Checking volume bitmap. 
** Checking volume information. 
** The volume MacBookSSD appears to be OK. 
disk0s2: I/O error. 
*****The volume was modified *****
```

```
diskutil list
```

shows for the affected disk0 the following output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                   TYPE NAME         SIZE        IDENTIFIER
0:  GUID_partition_scheme             *240.1 GB    disk0
1:                    EFI EFI          209.7 MB    disk0s1
2:              Apple_HFS MacBookSSD   239.1 GB    disk0s2
3:             Apple_Boot Recovery HD  650.0 MB    disk0s3
```

With `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0` I get:

```
Started partition map verification on disk0
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
Error: -69842: Couldn't mount disk
```

With `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk0` I get

```
Repairing the partition map might erase disk0s1, proceed? (y/N) y
Started partition map repair on disk0
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Adjusting partition map to fit whole disk as required
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
Error: -69697: Partition map repair failed while adjusting structures to fit current whole disk size
Underlying error: 5: Input/output error
```

So `diskutil` is apparently not capable of repairing my disk. In order to check for hardware defects I ran `dmesg` and get something like the following (showing only some lines from the bottom since it's a lot of output I can't copy here):

```
...
disk0s2: I/O error
jnl disk0s2: update_fs_block:failed to update block 2 (ret 5)
jnl: disk0s2: journal_open: Error replaying the journal!
hfs: early jnl init: failed to open/create the journal (retval 0).
hfs_mountfs: hfs_early_journal_init failed, setting to FSK
hfs(1): Journal replay fail. Writing lastMountVersion as FSK!
disk0s2: I/O error. 
hfs_mountfs: hfs_early_journal_init failed, erroring out
hfs_mount: hfs_mountfs returned error=22 for device disk0s2

...

disk0s1: I/O error. 
disk0s1: I/O error. 
disk0s1: I/O error. 
disk0s1: I/O error. 
msdosfs_fat_uninit_vol: error 5 from msdosfs_fat_cache_flush
Starting poll type 4
Restarting poll type 4
Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 ...
disk0: I/O error. 

...
```

Does this look like a hardware error to you and I should just install a new device?

PS: I've been able to mount /dev/disk0s2 with a CloneZilla USB stick in unix terminal and was able to save most of my data to an external file (unfortunately no installed applications...). However, mounting disk0s2 in Mac Recovery Terminal or single user mode still fails.

Update on free disk space: When I mount /dev/sda2 with the CloneZilla live USB Terminal, `df -h` shows a usage of about 79% (175G of 223G in use). Seems about right.

Comment: From reading some of the error output above, it may appear that there's a bad block on the startup SSD. If you only had some type of a hardware connection issue, it would be doubtful to get an error such as this. May be worth trying another SSD, being that costs have become more reasonable.

Comment: This is just a guess but how much free space do you have on your SSD?  Select the SSD and then type command-I. A window appears and it will tell you how much available space you have.

Comment: Using ```df -h``` from the Mac recovery terminal, I don't see my device /dev/disk0, probably since it can't be mounted. From ```diskutil list``` I can only see its total space.
I have, however, noted that I have up to 19 disks, with disk1 being the recovery partition with 1.9GB and disk2 - disk19 having sizes of 512KB up to 6MB. They're mounted on
```
/private/var/log
/Volumes
/private/var/tmp
/private/var/run
/System/Installation
/private/var/db
/Library/Preferences
```
amongst others. Is this normal?

I'll check for free disk space with the CloneZilla USB Terminal soon

Comment: CloneZilla live Terminal shows about 49G of free space (175G in use). 
Regarding bad blocks: does "bad block" mean a hardware fault? I have a new SSD available, but I'd rather love to recover my old system and continue to use the old SSD, avoiding electronic waste and keeping my applications. First try would be to reinstall OSX on the same disk, second try would be a new disk. However, repairing the disk and current installation would be best :)

Comment: There are some potential mitigations [here](https://superuser.com/questions/788747/how-to-fix-bad-blocks-on-ssd), but with some caveats.

Comment: I don't understand how your link can help me, or at least I don't understand what to do next

Answer (score 1):

To conclude so far: SATA cable was not damaged, as suggested somewhere else.

I came to the conclusion that the SSD itself is broken and I failed to repair it. Even GParted was also not able to format the partition.

Therefore I have just replaced the SSD with a new one. Luckily I was able to save most of the data, since the partition could still be accessed from a Linux system.

Comment: Excellent follow up. All signs were storage hardware. Thanks for answering this conclusively